# How to deal with a leaking 3rd party library from .net?

Tags: .net, pinvoke

I have the following situation:

I am using a third party .net library which calls into unmanaged code to do what it needs (the .net stuff is just a thin wrapper).  That library has various IDisposable implementations etc which I am wrapping in usings but it still leaks memory like an, err, sieve I suppose (I have been able to prove this conclusively in a unit test).

Ideally of course I would get the third party to fix their library but they are not responsive and I, sadly, cannot drop it either so what I am currently doing is this...

*The work I am doing with this third party library can be pretty easily encapsulated so where I need it I launch a process with a couple of command line arguments and capture the standard out.  That process does what it needs to do and returns a result object by simply serialising it to the standard out whereupon the method in the launching application which kicked off the process deserializes the result object and returns it just as if nothing freaky has happened.*

Obviously this is all pretty icky (command line argument parsing, serialising etc all adding complexity and slowing things down) but it has the advantage that it is pretty simple and it works (thankfully you can even turn off the window with CreateNoWindow so the user of the application doesn't notice anything untoward either).

Other approaches I thought about:

- Unloading app pools and whatnot but since the memory that is leaked is allocated outside of .net I figure that probably wouldn't help or would it?
- I also looked at trying to unload the DLL but it looks kind of fraught with danger - can I do this safely and reliably?

So, my question basically boils down to...

**Is there a way that I could keep everything in process and somehow clean the bottom of this third party library for it so I do not leak memory?**

Comment: What memory is exactly leaked? If you can find the pointer that is leaking, you can free it yourself.

Comment: Just curious, if it's so easily encapsulated by just wiring up stdin/stdout, why is it irreplaceable? (I've gone through similar annoyances so many times with 3rd party component developers that I really try to avoid them unless they're proven responsive or provide the source code).

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  The thing is I don't really have any access to any pointers - it wraps things up into collections of .Net objects and returns those so officially I only have access to the public surface of those objects.  Internally I am sure they probably have a heap of IntPtrs and whatnot around so perhaps I can dig into it's code with reflector and find out exactly what it is doing and then use reflection to get hold of the underlying IntPtr and free that but since I don't know what their unmanaged code is doing that feels decidedly risky

Comment: @silijon - the input is easy to encapsulate and the output is also easy but in order to get from one to the other it has to do a whole heap of really complex stuff (which I don't really understand) - the code in the exe that I am launching is pretty lengthy.  There are other options around but it would take a long time to learn them and we have the skills with this library already so we effectively have a working application (just it works for a short period of time before going loopy-bonkers on the memory front) and changing it would be months of effort which is tough to justify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...it still leaks memory like an, err, sieve I suppose (I have been able to prove this conclusively in a unit test).

I'm assuming the answer is 'no', but I have to ask -- is there any chance it "leaks" memory 
during normal use, but is smart enough to clean it all up when you "shut it down"?  I've encountered at least a few libraries whose internal caches seem to grow in an unbounded manner, but which get cleaned up when the library's termination routine is invoked.

Assuming the leaks are really just bugs, then...

> ...where I need it I launch a process with a couple of command line arguments and capture the standard out

...I think your approach here is the most reasonable one, given the parameters of the situation. In effect, you're hosting code that you don't "trust" -- perhaps not for security reasons, but for performance / reliability reasons.

> Unloading app pools and whatnot but since the memory that is leaked is allocated outside of .net I figure that probably wouldn't help or would it?

Correct -- that won't help.

> I also looked at trying to unload the DLL but it looks kind of fraught with danger - can I do this safely and reliably?

That most likely won't solve the problem. If the code is as buggy as you say, it's most likely not going to be good about cleaning up its allocated resources when it gets unloaded. (And the system isn't going to clean up its resources for it either--if it allocated a resource without freeing it, that resource will effectively leak.)

There's really not much you can do otherwise in this case. The only last-resort option I can think of is trying to hook / intercept the 3rd-party library's routines, somehow forcing all of its allocations into a pool that you can free all at once (after freeing the library). **But you really shouldn't try doing that.**  It's quite dangerous, almost certainly not worth the effort, too hard to implement correctly, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - yup the answer to your question is indeed no :-( - looks like I'll stick with my ropey approach then!